# Mono ServiceStack closes tcp connections prematurely

Tags: ubuntu, mono, ubuntu-14.04, servicestack

We have been trying to transfer large files via ServiceStack's customized HttpResult return type. However if the service is running under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Mono v4.4.2 the connection gets prematurely closed before we can read the whole file. Its very random in the amount of time it stays open, sometimes we can transfer 50MB, sometimes it closes at 4MB.

The exact same service with no code changes runs flawlessly under Windows and we have transferred files as large as 333MB.

We either need to know what causes the premature connection termination or how to setup servicestack/mono to allow the connection to stay open for a longer period of time.

Comment: Which web server (Apache/Nginx/XSP) do you use or you use HttpListener? Can you provide a small sample of service showing the connection drop while sending file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way to run ServiceStack on Mono is to use [Nginx, HyperFastCGI](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/mono-server-config) which we've found offers greater reliability over the default [Nginx/Mono FastCGI](http://FastCGI).

But ultimately Mono's HTTP Stack is inherently unreliable and performs poorly compared to Windows/.NET which we recommend using instead for heavy workloads.

The future for running .NET on Linux will be to use .NET Core, you can vote for [this feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/10286952-support-dnx) to get notified of ServiceStack's progress for .NET Core updates.